# DatabaseMetaData().getTables() - is very slow any alternative?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-performance, dbconnection, database-metadata

`DatabaseMetaData().getTables()` - is very slow, Is there any alternative of this?

Following is my actual code :

```
connection.getMetaData().getTables(null,null,null,new String[] {"TABLE", "VIEW"} );
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Try to narrow your search by providing catalog and schema names parameters.

Comment: I am using Oracle ,PostgreSQL and MySQL in single application.

Comment: Its business requirement to search for all the tables and views in the database (Oracle ,PostgreSQL or MySQL) selected by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly fire the below queries through statement in java and obtain the result in resultset

Oracle:

```
select tablespace_name, table_name from dba_tables;
```

MySQL:

```
show tables
```

PostgreSQL :

`SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables`;